# How are materialized CTE's stored in Postgres14

Tags: postgresql, postgres-14

I was able to significantly speed up a query that looks something as follows:

```
WITH MATERIALIZED t1 as (
    SELECT x1, x2 from v1 where v1.id = :id
) select * from t1
```

Here, `v1` is a view (unmaterialized). My question, where is the materialized result of `t1` stored? Is it stored in buffer cache or disk? I'm concerned about computing several materialized versions of `t1` for different values of `id` and polluting my buffer cache or OS cache.

Comment: Why do you use a CTE at all and not just `SELECT x1, x2 from v1 where v1.id = :id`?

Comment: the view is expensive to calculate and it provides up-to-date data so i can't materialize it

Comment: I assume that the referenced speed improvement was in a query that inluded multiple subqueries against `v1` and not the simple case in the original post. I haven't looked at the PostgreSQL internals to see how CTEs are stored, but I also don't think it particularly important. Either your environment has the resources to complete the query or it doesn't. Marking a CTE as `MATERIALIZED` means that the subquery will be evaluated only once for full query but also creates an optimization fence that prevents folding it into the larger query.

Comment: A CTE with the keyword MATERIALIZED is completely different from a MATERIALIZED VIEW. In a CTE it's just a barrier between the different sections of a query plan. For the VIEW it means that the results from the view will be stored like a table on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MATERIALIZED` does not imply that the data are stored on disk. It only means that the query executor will first compute the result of the CTE, then use it in the main statement. Essentially, it is an “optimizer barrier”: without `MATERIALIZED`, PostgreSQL can treat the CTE like a subquery and optimize further.

The `MATERIALIZED` in a CTE has nothing to do with materialized views: those are actually persisted in a database table. A CTE only exist in the statement that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the 12th version of the kernel, the behavior of the optimizer changes when calculating the query plan using CTE. Depending on certain circumstances, the optimizer may decide to use materialize or inline veiw. The algorithm of the optimizer when working with CTE is described in the document https://www.postgresql.eu/events/pgconfeu2022/sessions/session/3902/slides/354/CTEsAndTheirMaterialization-DivyaSharma.pdf

I can’t see your query plan, but I suspect that it’s about the same:

```
explain analyse with w as  materialized  (select * from operation)
select *
from w

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CTE Scan on w  (cost=10.50..11.50 rows=50 width=1576) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)               |
|  CTE w                                                                                                       |
|    ->  Seq Scan on operation  (cost=0.00..10.50 rows=50 width=1576) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)|
|Planning Time: 0.307 ms                                                                                       |
|Execution Time: 0.064 ms                                                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


explain analyse with w as not materialized  (select * from operation)
select *
from w

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Seq Scan on operation  (cost=0.00..10.50 rows=50 width=1576) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)|
|Planning Time: 0.056 ms                                                                               |
|Execution Time: 0.012 ms                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Use MATERIALIZED ;)